# How to add QMenuBar to QWizardPage?

Tags: qt, qmenubar, qwizardpage

I am trying to add a QMenuBar to QWizardPage

```
QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar;
menuBar->setNativeMenuBar(false);
QMenu *helpMenu = new QMenu;
QAction *helpAction = new QAction;

helpMenu->addAction(helpAction);
menuBar->addMenu(helpMenu);

layout->addWidget(menuBar);
//Other widgets
setLayout(layout);
```

But I can't see the menu bar.

Basically I want to add an "Help" menu with "About product" item to display the product version and licensing information that we generally see in many applications. I am on Windows 10 using QT 5.13.2

Comment: Do you want the QMenuBar only to be displayed in a QWizardPage or in all or only in some?

Comment: I want it on all the wizard pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use a QMainWindow where you set the QMenuBar and use the QWizard as centralWidget:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    // menubar
    QMenuBar * menuBar = w.menuBar();
    QMenu *helpmenu = menuBar->addMenu("Help");
    QAction *aboutaction = helpmenu->addAction("About product");
    QObject::connect(aboutaction, &QAction::triggered, [&w](){
        QMessageBox::information(&w, "About", "About");
    });

    QWizard *wizard = new QWizard;

    // add pages
    wizard->addPage(new QWizardPage);
    wizard->addPage(new QWizardPage);

    w.setCentralWidget(wizard);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```